# PIC microcontroller - port b working

Tags: microcontroller, pic, port

Can someone please explain to me how this port works? 
[image]

Comment: How what works?

Comment: There's a description in the datasheet. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand the role of the schmitt trigger buffer basically.

Comment: This question is too vague.  The diagram explains evereything nicely.  Without asking what specifically you don't understand, this needs to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

By your question, I assume you know how a Schmitt trigger works.  If not, you can [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger).

You didn't say which PIC you are referring to; the circuits for the different PIC's are similar but not all identical -- not just across families (PIC10, PIC16, etc.) but even within the same family.

The diagram you included in your question almost exactly matches with the one in the datasheet for the PIC16F877, so I will use that.

The Schmitt trigger is only shown going to unspecified "Peripheral Module".  However in the PIC16F877, the only pins in Port B with special functionality are RB0/INT, RB6/PGD, and RB7/PGC.  (RB3/PGM is also marked a special, but modern programmers don't use it.)

So it appears they are using the Schmitt trigger input for these special functions, to clear up any external signals (using the inherent hysteresis nature of the  Schmitt trigger), and regular TTL inputs for the regular Read Port functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the pin descriptions page of the datasheet for your particular PIC, you will see that they describe the input thresholds of the pins.  Let's use the example of a PIC16f677, just because I use that part.  Find the similar page number of your exact chip.

I'm using datasheet DS41262E which covers the parts PIC16F631/677/685/687/689/690

Look at Page 14, Table 1-1 and titled: Pinout Description

Notice that each pin is listed, along with the descriptions of what that pin might be used for.  Input type is shown as TTL, ST or AN.

TTL is just what it says: TTL compatible.  Logic 0 is less than 0.8V, logic 1 is greater than 2.4V.

ST stands for Schmitt Trigger.  This means that a logic 0 is below some value (usually about 20% of Vdd, a logic 1 is above some value (usually about 80% of Vdd), and the input remains in whatever state it was last in if the voltage should move in between those two thresholds.  It's great for cleaning up noisy input signals.

AN is an analog input.

The bottom line is that a pin might have a TTL threshold for one function but a ST or analog input stage for other functions *on that same pin*.